# Focus for UI that is used in 3d app

Tags: python-2.7, pyside, 3dsmax

I have a UI that I have made which is to perform tasks within 3ds max. When I open the ui in Max via a python.ExecuteFile call in a toolbar maxscript, focus and keyboard entries are given to the ui elements, using the max command DisableAccelerators(), so that fields can be entered and then run via an execute button. If I click onto the main max window to do something before I have finished the input to the ui, the focus is lost and keyboard shortcuts are restored to max. If I then click on the UI again to continue editing/updating, the focus remains with Max and I cannot continue using the UI.

I am using PySide and have tried setting the UI window to have strong focus     ( setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus) ), but this has not worked so far, so does anybody know what I need to research or look up to help me with this? I just need to understand how to shift focus back and forth between the App window and the UI I have created.

Thanks

I have been looking into mouse events to identify the window that I click on to run a function that sets a boolean if the right window name is returned, Would this be a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

The following link should help.  I doubt you'll be able to do your work with PySide, as the proposed solution assumes using a PyQt4 build supplied by Blur Studio as part of their 3ds Max tool set.  That being said, PyQt4 and PySide are substantially similar, so unless there's a very specific reason why you need to use PySide over PyQt4, you should be fine.

http://area.autodesk.com/blogs/chris/pyqt-ui-in-3ds-max-2014-extension

Comment: I should have put that I am using Maxplus in Max 2015 to test calls to a custom UI. The implementation by Autodesk is woefully inadequate and there is a lot of code missing that deals with parenting to the main max window, but we have managed to sort this out without Blur Python (which currently is not supported in Max 2015) and are using a different method to parent our custom UI to the max 2015 window. It has been a ballache to get a response from Autodesk, except that they did ask that if we find a solution, we should pass it onto them so they can finish the implementation for others to use

Comment: We currently use Blur Python in max 2011, which works well but we wanted to test the Pyside based maxplus system in max 2015. I have seen all the Chris Diggins stuff, but the implementation in 2015 has not progressed much beyond what he did two years ago. What we have now works well. Once it is approved and stable, I can look at sharing it for others.

Comment: There is actually a build of BlurPython for 2015, but it's currently behind closed doors (not at Blur).  I need to work with them to get their changes merged in (https://github.com/blurstudio/Py3dsMax).  Regardless, glad it sounds like you have a solution that works for you.  I'd love to see Max itself progress far enough that third-party plugins and hacks aren't needed any longer.  Maybe one day...

Comment: I notice that Max 2017 effectively has Blur Python inside it now. Hopefully, python scripting will be a little easier. Why they did not adopt the Maya python format is beyond me, it would have made life easier.

Comment: It does, and in 2016 and 2017 there are now native methods of parenting a Qt dialog/window to Max's main window.See MaxPlus.AttachQWidgetToMax()